# How to burn debian iso to usb

Tags: linux, debian, system-installation, usb, iso

I downloaded the debian amd 64-bit iso file (apx 650 mb) on a macbook w/retina (i.e. no cd drive) running OS X. I'm trying to dual boot and have already gotten rEFInd working. Set up partition for Debian with MS-DOS(FAT) format and blessed it. Now I'm trying to burn the .iso onto a usb to use for installation on the same computer. I'm using Terminal to convert .iso to .img with: `hdiutil convert -format UDRW -o ./debian-7.8.0-amd64-CD-1\ \(1\).img ./debian-7.8.0-amd64-CD-1\ \(1\).iso`
but it keeps outputting `hdiutil: convert failed - No such file or directory`
Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

EDIT: I've succeeded in converting the .iso to .img and I'm attempting to unmount the disk partition I've made for debian via `diskutil unmountDisk /dev/disk0s5` but I keep getting `Unmount of disk0 failed: at least one volume could not be unmounted`. I've verified this is the right disk using `diskutil list`. Any ideas what is wrong?

Comment: Does `ls` show the debian iso file in your present working directory?

Comment: No. It turns out I was in the wrong directory. I changed directories, and this caused the convert to run but there was a syntax error. After renaming the file to so the input was `./debian-7.8.0-amd64-CD-1` it ran properly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can burn your iso file directly to usb by the command dd

```
sudo dd if=<Your iso file location> of=/dev/<Your usb drive>(usually=/dev/sdb)
```

**note**:use  **sudo fdisk -l** to see what is your usb device name

Example : i connect my usb thumb drive ,then i type sudo fdisk -l to show my device name , its (/dev/sdb) so i will type :
sudo dd if=./debian-7.8.0-amd64-CD-1 of=/dev/sdb

[image]

Comment: I usually run `dmesg` to see what device is added most recently (i.e. near the end of the output).

Comment: Thanks for the tip, both of you. I was planning to copy the .img directly to the partition using `$ sudo dd if=debian7.8.0-amd64-CD-1.img of=/dev/disk0s5 bs=1m`instead of burning to usb. Would that work?

Answer (score 4):

The [Debian installation guide](https://www.debian.org/releases/stable/amd64/ch04s03.en.html#usb-copy-isohybrid) now recommends the simpler `cp` command to write an ISO image to a USB drive:

```
# cp debian.iso /dev/sdX
# sync
```

This requires root or sudo access and `sdX` is the relevant USB device (eg. `/dev/sdb`), not the partition (eg `/dev/sdb1`).